# Why is my React Native component not re-rendering on state update?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-maps, react-native-maps

I'm struggling with this React-Native component for a few days now. You should probably know that React-Native is kind of new to me so... sorry if the solution is obvious to you.

I'm using react-native-maps and I have several markers on my map. Each one of them has some data stored in my state and I want the callout to display a piece of this state on press.
Here are my states :

```
const [markersDetails, setMarkersDetails] = useState([]);
const [activeMarker, setActiveMarker] = useState({});
```

My activeMarker is updated by this function :

```
const markerSearch = (markerId) => {
  let stockMarker = markersDetails.find((singleMarker) => {
    return Number(singleMarker.idMarker) === markerId;
  });
  console.log("Stock ", stockMarker);
  setActiveMarker(stockMarker);
  console.log("State ", activeMarker);
};
```

And this function is called, inside my return, with the onPress of any marker :

```
<Marker
  key={Number(marker.index)}
  coordinate={{
    latitude: Number(marker.latitude),
    longitude: Number(marker.longitude),
  }}
  pinColor="blue"
  onPress={() => {
    markerSearch(Number(marker.index));
  }}
>
  {activeMarker !== {} && activeMarker.markerName && (
    <Callout>
      <View>
        <Text>{activeMarker.markerName}</Text>
      </View>
    </Callout>
  )}
</Marker>
```

But whenever I press on a marker, the callout opens immediatly while my state is not yet updated. So the text within the callout refers either to the previous marker or is empty (if it's the first marker I press on).
I've checked with console.log and my state is clearly updated but it takes a little bit more time. And I don't know why my callout is not re-rendering when this state is updating.
I've tried a ton of things to make this works but I can't figure this out...

Comment: In onPress you mean marker.index its look like it is the index in markersDetails array,
and in markerSearch function where you use find you use the value of singleMarker element in the array, i think you maybe need to change it to:
let stockMarker = markersDetails.find((singleMarker, singleMarkerIndex) => {
      return singleMarkerIndex === markerId;
    });

Comment: Thank you for your input @elirand5 but this solution is not working in this case, the "index" here is not the place inside the array but inside the database, so they're not the same.
Anyway, the problem is still the difference between state update speed and component rendering speed and/or the lack of re-rendering once the state is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like that:

1. You can extract the  section to a new component
2. Then inside this use the useEffect hook

```
export default function CalloutComponent({activeMarker}) {
  const [markerName, setMarkerName] = useState('')
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setMarkerName(activeMarker?.markerName)
  }, [activeMarker?.markerName])

  if(!!markerName) return null

  return (
    <Callout>
      <View>
        <Text>{markerName}</Text>
      </View>
    </Callout>
  )
}
```

3. And use this new component in your Main view

```
<Marker
  ...
>
  <CalloutComponent activeMarker={activeMarker}/>
</Marker>
```

Comment: Thank you Juan for your input. Unfortunately, I already extracted the callout to another component earlier today and the problem remains the same.